# Coose server hardware for private server

Tags: linux, centos, hardware, database

I am planning to run a Linux server for hosting a java spring application with Tomcat.

I need some help to choose the right server hardware to buy.

NOTE: I am a student and cannot afford any really expensive hardware.
Which means that you do not need to tell me that, normal servers use ecc ram, have no graphics card(not even onboard) and so on...

I am planning to spend around 500€ for the server.

My requirements are:

- is not that expensive
- Can run 24/7 for months (or if this is not possible in the low-budget    segment i would like something like 23/7[1 hour downtime per day       should be not soo much of an problem]) 
   can run an linux based OS
- i would like CentOS or something similar
- performane:

  - i expect therequest to be rather database heavy, as the server will mainly    query    some data from the database and return it.
  - Therefore i am planning to use ssd(128gb should be more than enough) - i would like to use a raid 1 system
  - i expect about 20000 requests per hour at peak, which makes about 6 requests per second at peak
  - During the non peak time ido not expect more than 5k requests per hour

Additional nice features would be that the server is small and doesn´t need much energy 
Internet connection shouldn´t be the problem.

Hardware that i found and that looks pretty good:(though i do not not if such an hardware is appropriate for serverhosting) 
1. http://www.amazon.de/Intel-NUC-Kit-D34010WYK-Computing-Generation/dp/B00GPJ83EU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1428159884&sr=8-1&keywords=intel+nuc+i3 
I would buy 2 ssd and 2 x 4gb of ram for this

2.http://www.amazon.de/GIGABYTE-GB-BXi3-4010-Barebone-i3-4010U-USB3/dp/B00GK9WMD8/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1428160085&sr=8-1&keywords=gigabyte+brix+i3 
More or less the same as the intel nuc

And here is the reason why i wrote this question. 
Are the linked products somehow usable as servers? 
Or are there other cheap alternatives that are far supperior? 
Or is there simply no way do get a realativly decent server for my budget?

Please, also note that i am not very experieced with hosting servers, so if i am planning something completely wrong, please tell me ;)

Comment: Wrong site my friend.  Shopping questions are generally off topic on all StackExchange sites, and this site in particular is only for professional sysadmins, plus or minus some people like me who fool the others :-).  You'd have better luck asking on some discussion site.

Comment: oh, i am sorry then...
can you suggest such a "server shoppping forum"? ;)

Comment: I'm not active in it, but AnandTech forums might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Why buy a physical server? Just get an Azure or AWS virtual machine and go with it. No upfront cost, no maintenance, you pay what you use, and you can scale performance up and down depending on your workload.